# How can a neutron star have a magnetic field when its particles are neutral?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, astrophysics, neutron-stars

I understand that it is a celestial object of very small radius (typically 18 miles/30 km) and very high density, composed predominantly of closely packed neutrons. Neutron stars are thought to form by the gravitational collapse of the remnant of a massive star after a supernova explosion, provided that the star is insufficiently massive to produce a black hole.

Question:

1. How can a  neutron star have a magnetic field when its particles are neutral?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the answer is there: neutron stars are mostly neutrons but do have some charged constituents.

Comment: The answer is not there. It is : "The origins of the strong magnetic field are as yet unclear." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_star#Magnetic_field

Comment: There are good answers here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/207807/do-the-magnetic-moments-of-neutrons-mutually-align-to-produce-the-magnetic-field?rq=1

Comment: Neutrons are electrical neutral elements but have a magnetic dipole moment. So it is not surprising to me that the neutrons of a neutron star have a common magnetic field.